# How do I block a protocol using iptables firewall

Tags: firewall, iptables

How to block a specific protocol using iptables firewall? For example block Yahoo messenger?

Answer (score 3):

Well, in this case you probably want to block the *ports* Yahoo Messenger uses, not the protocol (which is TCP/UDP, used by almost everything else).

Based on [this list](http://www.helpbytes.co.uk/yconnect.php), I would start with port 5050 outbound and perhaps add more:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 5050 -j DROP
```

Once you have a set of rules that you have determined is sufficient, don't forget to save them with `iptables-save` (or they will be lost upon reboot).

Comment: it didn't work :/

Comment: I didn't say it would, you need to find out which ports are being used right now, and if there isn't a current list, use something like Wireshark. It's complicated, sorry...